# Heroku app not working on remote

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, deployment, remote-server

I am deploying a simple node.js application. It seems to run fine locally (I see all the functionality I have written so far), but when I run:

```
heroku open cool
```

I just see a blank page.

Here are my logs:

```
2016-03-28T19:03:04.567334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-03-28T19:03:04.568049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-03-28T19:03:09.551701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-03-28T19:03:11.228745+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2016-03-28T19:03:12.390081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2016-03-28T21:08:49.503946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-03-28T21:08:49.504269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-03-28T21:08:51.391775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-03-28T21:08:56.437135+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-28T21:08:56.437149+00:00 app[web.1]: > transloc@1.0.0 start /app
2016-03-28T21:08:56.437150+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-03-28T21:08:56.437151+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-28T21:08:57.152952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-03-28T21:08:58.586930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cool" host=still-depths-35391.herokuapp.com request_id=6feab52c-143c-4353-bbbc-696355042cbc fwd="152.3.43.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=1764
2016-03-28T21:08:58.910098+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/server.js" host=still-depths-35391.herokuapp.com request_id=5c3ab4d4-0a5d-48fa-b272-7c82000da3dd fwd="152.3.43.142" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1764
2016-03-28T21:08:58.960943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=still-depths-35391.herokuapp.com request_id=e7a35c05-da23-4a47-995e-98f015ea08ed fwd="152.3.43.142" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1764
```

Comment: i can see that its loading the page correctly here http://still-depths-35391.herokuapp.com/cool

Comment: I can see app working [http://still-depths-35391.herokuapp.com/](http://still-depths-35391.herokuapp.com/). Please share If you see same logs more than once.

Comment: I didn't realize I had https everywhere, it wouldn't route on that. Thanks, there seems to be no issue.